# Can I safely use dequed tableView cell as prototype

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am using prototype cell to calculate real cell height. Since I'm using storyboard I have chosen to create prototype cell by dequeing it. Example code:

```
- (MyCell *)prototypePriceOptionCell
{
    if (_prototypeCell == nil) {
        _prototypeCell = (MyCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    return _prototypePriceOptionCell;
}
```

This prototype is never returned to `tableView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Will it be dequed by table view to reuse and show it in table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You technically could, from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a):

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell
>   must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its
>   initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this
>   method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an
>   existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s
>   prepareForReuse method instead.

But it also states that it can return nil under some circumstances.
However, I wouldn't use your approach, not because it wouldn't work but because it's not supposed to be used like that. This means that you have weak code relying on a feature it's not supposed to be used like that.

My suggestion, instantiate your cell manually calling the appropriate methods. Also, I like to have my cells on separate xibs, away from storyboards.

**Edit:**
Answering your question at the end, yes, the cell can and will be dequeued by the table view if you call dequeue in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`